# Show 0 for values with missing data

Tags: tableau-api

I have a dimension I am showing in a text table that can have one of 3 possibilities "A", "B", or "C" and I want at all times to have A, B and C shown in a text table even if one of them has 0 occurrences. The issue is that I am filtering this based on date, so it is possible that for example B may not exist, but I still want to have a 0 printed for B.

I have gone to Analysis -> Table layout -> show empty rows which will show "B", but in the count display it shows a blank. How can I get it to display a 0?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is very famous among tableau users and I still did not see a generic **tableau-only** solution. All proper solutions start with injecting rows to your data which I assume you do not want this.

Below method will only work if you have a Date Dimension on the measure and **no-data** dates are **not** completely filtered-out; so you will be seeing zeros even though that date has no data as you may see on below screenshot.

[image]

When you filter out the **no-data** dates, unfortunately you will keep on seeing NULLs.

---

If you are using the `SUM` of `Number of Records` as your occurrences, then you may create a calculated field as below and use it in your pane:

```
ZN(LOOKUP(SUM([Number of Records]),0))
```

You can leave the **Default Table Calculation** as **Automatic** so the **Results are computed along Table (accross).**